# Условия в псевдоклассах css

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .class{
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            font-size: 50px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .class:hover{
            border-color: red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="class">test</div>
    <div class="class"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

При наведении на блок его контур станет красным, но я хочу сделать это так, чтобы цвет изменялся только для пустого блока, а блок с текстом цвет не менял. Как это сделать с помощью псевдоклассов  css не прибегая к js. И как вообще в псевдоклассах сделать какое-либо условие,которое применяет стили по логике if-a или более сложной структуры?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.class:empty:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="class">test</div>
<div class="class"></div>
```

И наоборот:

```css
.class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.class:not(:empty):hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="class">test</div>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если наоборот чтобы пустой блок цвет не менял что должно быть вместо empty?

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук `.class:not(:empty):hover`

Comment: Спасибо, как называются empty, not(empty) одним словом? =) Чтобы знать что мне гуглить и учить.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes